# node js get doesnt get anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I'm currently learning how to build a Rest API with Node Js and MongoDB, so naturally I've been following some tutorials, and when the time came, I've setup an example but it doesn't work.

I have 2 main files, **app.js** and **historic.js** (model).

On **app.js** I have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

Historic =require('./models/historic');

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useMongoClient: true });

var db = mongoose.connection;

console.log('Here');
db.on('error', function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  } 
});

db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('Mongo db connected successfully');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Please use /api/historic');
});


app.get('/api/historics', (req, res) => {
    Historic.getHistorics((err, historic) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(historic);
    });
});

app.listen(27017);
console.log('Running on port 27017...');
```

Then on my model I have the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Historic Schema
const historicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    timestamp:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const Historic = module.exports = mongoose.model('Historic', historicSchema);

// Get Historics
module.exports.getHistorics = (callback, limit) => {
    console.log('Get Historics-Historic');
    Historic.find(callback).limit(limit);
    console.log('Get Historics-Historic-After find');
    console.log(limit);
}
```

Whenever I try to access http://localhost:27017/api/historics/ I only get: [].

I know that I have data on my DB as you can see on the image:
[data on DB test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fge99.png)

Any tips?

Comment: in your `app.get` where do you specify mongoose query?

Comment: Can you log the result of Historic.getHistorics in `app.get('/api/historics')` ?

Comment: Hello Alex, when I log res I get a huge result that I can't paste here because it's too long.

Comment: Check the log here: https://pastebin.com/1V4L469e   @Alex83690

Comment: Can you give me an example @MikeTung

Comment: @Alex83690 yes, that's my theory as well. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @NunoPontes try to change `Historic.find(callback).limit(limit);` to `Historic.find({}, callback).limit(limit);`

Comment: @Alex83690 it didn't work. And I just saw now, that it seems on a loop as the browser has the loading icon always

Comment: @Alex83690 it's in an infinity loop and now doesn't appear anything

Answer (score 0):

According to Docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html the callback should be at least the 2nd parameter of the .find method.
Try to replace

```
    // Get Historics
module.exports.getHistorics = (callback, limit) => {
    console.log('Get Historics-Historic');
    Historic.find(callback).limit(limit);
    console.log('Get Historics-Historic-After find');
    console.log(limit);
}
```

to

```
// Get Historics
module.exports.getHistorics = (callback, limit) => {
var query = Historic.find({});
query.limit(limit);
query.exec(callback);
}
```

Comment: It's in an infinity loop as well. It keeps loading forever

Comment: What is the result of `JSON.stringify(historic)` in the callback (add it before res.json(historic))

Comment: (node:11036) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4951#issuecomment-278081233 What is your version ? See also https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4951#issuecomment-283327958. Sorry, I can not help you anymore about the really mongoose-specific issues.

Comment: Version: mongoose@4.13.8

Answer (score 0):

I've been told the solution and it works.

Old Code:

```
const historicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    timestamp:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Solution:

```
const historicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    timestamp:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {collection: 'historic'});
```

I needed add the collection name that was defined on Mongoose